# How to match a fixed number of digits with regex in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I want to retrieve the consecutive 8 digits out of a string.

```
"hello world,12345678anything else"
```

should return `12345678` as result(the space in between is optional).

But this should not return anything:

```
"hello world,123456789anything else"
```

Because it has 9 digits,I only need 8 digits unit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
'/(?<!\d)\d{8}(?!\d)/'
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what `(?<!\d)` and `(?!\d)` mean?

Comment: @user198729, those are look behind, and look ahead, `!` mean not, so \d shouldn't come before and after of \d{8}, for more info, see http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: These are referred to as "zero-width look-around assertions".  There's a whole class of RE atoms that start with `(?`; the ones in this example are followed by `!`, to indicate that they match what's coming up as long as it doesn't match what's after the `!`, or `<!`, to indicate that they match negatively against what just passed.  So `(?<!\d) will match at any point in the string that doesn't immmediately follow a numeric digit.  They are called 'zero-width' because they don't actually add anything to the match.

Comment: More precisely,`(?<!\d)` is look ahead,and `(?!\d)` behind,right?

Comment: @S.Mark,I found.But why?It's opposite to the intuitive,isn't it?

Comment: @user198729, I mean, `(?<!\d)` is look behind and `(?!\d)` is look ahead

Comment: Yes,that's why I say it's counter intuitive.`(?<!\d)` is positioned **ahead** but called **look behind**

Comment: yeah it's like a rear-view mirror.

Comment: @user198729, Imm, sorry I dont get it, `(?<!\d)` is positioned behind `\d{8}` in my eye.

Comment: Yeah it matches anything (or nothing) that **isn't** a digit.  `(?<=\d)` would match anything that is.  Note that (?<=\D) doesn't work in this situation because it will only match if there's something there, ie not at the beginning of the string or line.

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = "hello world,12345678798anything else";
preg_match('/[0-9]{8}/',$var,$match);
echo $match[0];
```

Comment: There is already a solution almost exactly like this which we have determined doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to match the stuff on either side of the 8 digits.  You can do this with zero-width look-around assertions, as exemplified by @S Mark, or you can take the simpler route of just creating a backreference for the 8 digits:

```
preg_match('/\D(\d{8})\D/', $string, $matches)
$eight_digits = $matches[1];
```

But this won't match when the digits start or end a line or string; for that you need to elaborate it a bit:

```
preg_match('/(?:\D|^)(\d{8})(?:\D|$)/', $string, $matches)
$eight_digits = $matches[1];
```

The `(?:...)` in this one allows you to specify a subset of alternates, using `|`, without counting the match as a back-reference (ie adding it to the elements in the array `$matches`).

For many more gory details of the rich and subtle language that is Perl-Compatible Regular Expression syntax, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php